# Nested association queries. Query scope

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to scope records to what belong to the current user. But I'm not having much success. Here is what I'm trying:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user_id = Map.get(Statcasters.Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn), :id)
    user = Repo.get!(User, user_id) |> Repo.preload(:leagues)

    league = Repo.get(user.leagues, id)
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [%Statcasters.League{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "leagues">, id: 16, inserted_at: ~N[2018-05-05 22:13:23.675833], name: "Cam's League", player_limit: 10, updated_at: ~N[2018-05-05 22:13:23.675843], users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>, users_leagues: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users_leagues is not loaded>}]
```

What makes records "queryable"? I guess passing a list into the Repo.get is not valid. So, what should I pass in that would properly scope the leagues to the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `user.leagues` is a `List` of preloaded associated records. If you need to find a record in that list, what about using [Enum.find/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3) for this:

```
Enum.find user.leagues, fn league -> league.id == id end
```

Otherwise, a `league` can just be loaded by `id` out of `Repo`, you don't need to scope `leagues` by `user_id`, since there's one unique record with the provided `id`:

```
Repo.get League, id
```